# Como se puede usar una api en express solo para proyectos en el mismo servidor? (IP)

Tags: nodejs, express

tengo un proyecto en un servidor VPS y en el mismo una api corriendo con Node y Express, está api es accesible desde fuera y dentro del servidor sin problemas, pero me gustaría que a esta api pudiera solo ser accedida por paginas o app corriendo en el mismo servidor.

Proble utilizando app.listen(8080, 'localhost');, pero nada

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar el modulo ***cors*** con  `npm i --save cors` luego agregas el siguiente middleware a express:

```js
app.use('*', cors({origin: <ruta de acceso>}))
```